# metadata is missing in document library sharepoint

Tags: document

When I import library from site A to site B in sharepoint site collection its metadata values get lost in site B.
How to recover the metadata? Do i need to manually do it.

Comment: How are you importing the library?

Comment: By metadata values, you mean info in managed metadata column or other security info like created/modified details?

Comment: i have exported and then imported through powershell command. managed metadata of document library field. like for dropdown columns.